# How to use Linux ip utility to determine interface sending to IPv4 multicast group?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, multicast

I have a Linux multicast application that will send to multicast group IPv4 address 232.1.1.1 and I want to know which local interface it will use by default. I believe the ip(1) utility should show me, but I've been unable to determine how (though not for lack of trying, however). If you know how, then please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ip route command with the -d flag to display multicast routing information:

"ip route get to 232.1.1.1"

Comment: Thanks! Just FYI, the "to" appears to be unnecessary.